# force Highcharts redraw animation when changing graph type

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a bunch of graphs that by default, come out as line graphs.  I've added buttons to the side of my graph to allow the user to change it to a pie, bar, areaspline, or back to line.

When the user clicks the button, it runs this function:

```
function change_graph_type(moduleNumber, type) {

  graph_type = type;

  var chart    = $('#graph' + moduleNumber).highcharts();

  for ( i=0;i<chart.series.length;i++ ) {
    chart.series[i].update({
      type      : graph_type
    });
    //chart.redraw();  //I've tried adding this here to no avail...
  } 
}
```

The code changes each series from e.g. - line to bar, or bar to areaspline, but I cannot figure out how to get the "animation" when the user toggles over to that new graph type, so it only runs the very first time the user generates the chart.

Comment: You can remove your series and it again with new type parameter. It will be better for your performance that destroying your chart and making it again. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrpLc32/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i tried many ways but there is no such function which fires `animation` after `redraw`

so created this below quick and dirty method which might help

http://jsfiddle.net/msekpj8m/

```js
$(function() {
    var chartOptions = {
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            showEmpty: false
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        yAxis: {
            showEmpty: false
        },

        series: [{
            allowPointSelect: true,
            data: [ // use names for display in pie data labels
                ['January', 29.9],
                ['February', 71.5],
                ['March', 106.4],
                ['April', 129.2],
                ['May', 144.0],
                ['June', 176.0],
                ['July', 135.6],
                ['August', 148.5], {
                    name: 'September',
                    y: 216.4,
                    selected: true,
                    sliced: true
                },
                ['October', 194.1],
                ['November', 95.6],
                ['December', 54.4]
            ],
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }]
    };
    var container = $('#container');
    container.highcharts(chartOptions);

    // Set type
    $.each(['line', 'column', 'spline', 'area', 'areaspline', 'scatter', 'pie'], function(i, type) {
        $('#' + type).click(function() {
            container.highcharts().destroy();
            chartOptions.chart.type = type;
            container.highcharts(chartOptions);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

<button id="column" style="margin-left: 2em">Column</button>
<button id="line">Line</button>
<button id="spline">Spline</button>
<button id="area">Area</button>
<button id="areaspline">Areaspline</button>
<button id="scatter">Scatter</button>
<button id="pie">Pie</button>
```